# PYOMO : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to match best parameters to fit an experimental curve.
To do so, I want my solver to minimize the sum of the squarred residuals. Would anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong ?
Thank you !

```
print(len(X))
print(len(Y))

model = ConcreteModel()
model.FRAT5= Var(domain=PositiveReals , initialize =3)
model.PRICE0 = Var(domain=PositiveIntegers , initialize = 400)

model.price0_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.PRICE0 >= 51)
model.FRAT5_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.FRAT5 >= 0.05  )

residuals = [    (exp(- (-log(0.5)/(model.FRAT5 - 1 )) * (X[k]/model.PRICE0 -1) ) - Y[k] )  for k in range(len(X)) ]

model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(residuals[k]**2 for k in range(len(X))), sense=minimize)

SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt').solve(model).write()
```

ANSWER :

```
100
100

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-127-d00a8ec5b470> in <module>()
      9 model.FRAT5_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.FRAT5 >= 0.05  )
     10 
---> 11 residuals = [    (exp(- (-log(0.5)/(model.FRAT5 - 1 )) * (X[k]/model.PRICE0 -1) ) - Y[k] )  for k in range(len(X)) ]
     12 
     13 model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(residuals[k]**2 for k in range(len(X))), sense=minimize)

<ipython-input-127-d00a8ec5b470> in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 model.FRAT5_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.FRAT5 >= 0.05  )
     10 
---> 11 residuals = [    (exp(- (-log(0.5)/(model.FRAT5 - 1 )) * (X[k]/model.PRICE0 -1) ) - Y[k] )  for k in range(len(X)) ]
     12 
     13 model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(residuals[k]**2 for k in range(len(X))), sense=minimize)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyomo` objects, including variables, are just objects used to pass a math construct into a solver.  So you cannot use them in the general expression that you have for `residuals`.

You *should* be able to express them directly inside of your objective expression, so try just moving your residual expression into your objective function, squaring it there, and summing them up.

=======
edit:

I take back what I said about `residuals`.  That expression does work (at lease on my version).  I'm a little surprised.  Anyhow, this constructs the model for me (without solving).  It is exactly your code with notional `X` and `Y` stuffed in.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

X = [1,2,3]
Y = [4,5,6]
model = ConcreteModel()
model.FRAT5= Var(domain=PositiveReals , initialize =3)
model.PRICE0 = Var(domain=PositiveIntegers , initialize = 400)

model.price0_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.PRICE0 >= 51)
model.FRAT5_constraint = Constraint(expr = model.FRAT5 >= 0.05  )

residuals = [    (exp(- (-log(0.5)/(model.FRAT5 - 1 )) * (X[k]/model.PRICE0 -1) ) - Y[k] )  for k in range(len(X)) ]

model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(residuals[k]**2 for k in range(len(X))), sense=minimize)

model.pprint()
```

#### Generates:

```
2 Var Declarations
    FRAT5 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :     3 :  None : False : False : PositiveReals
    PRICE0 : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     1 :   400 :  None : False : False : PositiveIntegers

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : (exp(- 0.6931471805599453/(FRAT5 - 1)*(1/PRICE0 - 1)) - 4)**2 + (exp(- 0.6931471805599453/(FRAT5 - 1)*(2/PRICE0 - 1)) - 5)**2 + (exp(- 0.6931471805599453/(FRAT5 - 1)*(3/PRICE0 - 1)) - 6)**2

2 Constraint Declarations
    FRAT5_constraint : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body  : Upper : Active
        None :  0.05 : FRAT5 :  +Inf :   True
    price0_constraint : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body   : Upper : Active
        None :  51.0 : PRICE0 :  +Inf :   True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint. You mean somethinge like this :

`model.obj = Objective(expr=sum([ (exp(- (-log(0.5)/(model.FRAT5 - 1 )) * (X[k]/model.PRICE0 -1) ) - Y[k] )  for k in range(len(X)) ]**2 for k in range(len(X))), sense=minimize)`

unfortunately, this does not solve the error, do you have something else in mind ?

Comment: Thank you, I finally solved the issue. It helped me a lot to see your comment. I still do not know why it did not work, because it does work with your suggested input value X,Y but not with my vectors of real numbers. More surprisingly it work when I put `-(model.PRICE0 - X[k])/model.PRICE0)` but does not work with `(X[k] - model.PRICE0  )/model.PRICE0)`   
Anyway, it does work now,thank you so much!